# Vectors - Shortest Distance From A Point To A Line

Tags: vectors

[image: SEE ATTACHED IMAGE FOR QUESTION]

So far, I have completed questions a and b, but am stuck, on question c. I have looked up an atoll, and found that it is a ring shaped island. The wording of the question is not very good, as obviously if the yacht kept going in a straight line, it obviously, would hit the reef at some point, so I'm not too sure what it is asking.
The parametric equations for the path of the yacht are:
x=-6-5t and y=10-15t

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: The reef is intended to be a circle around the beacon.  The yacht is moving in a straight line and it is perfectly possible that the straight line will miss the circle entirely.

Comment: Hint:  It is clear that the line does not go through the origin.  At the point,$P$, of closest approach, the vector from $P$ to the origin will be perpendicular to the line.

Comment: Correct me if wrong: Beacon at (0,0). Consider an 8 km circle around the origin. In part b you have calculated the time when the yacht is closest to (0,0). Get the (x,y) coordinates of this point and calculate the distance to (0,0). If greater than 8 km you can join the excursion, if less you stay away . Helps?